# Understanding the parameter passing issue in programming languages

Tags: parameter-passing

I am trying to find out exactly what are the parameter passing methods. What they do, what are their differences... I have the following subprogram:

```
subprogram p(x)
   a[1] = 6;
   element = 2;
   x = x + 3;
end
```

a is an array and has only two elements.

```
a[1] = 1 
a[2] = 2
element = 1
```

we call the subprogram as follows:

```
p(a[element])
```

Then what would be the results if the subprogram uses "pass by value", "pass by result", "pass by value-result", "pass by reference", or "pass by name" methods.

I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesnt matter what language it is. sometimes you use pass by value, sometimes pass by reference. what are differences what I asked

Comment: Pass by name depends on whether calling the name makes call by value, reference or value-result. In this case, if calling the name gives reference, it will change `a[2]` to 5, but call by value only gives the `a[2]` to the function, but doesn't change the `a[2]` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The language affects the scope of the variables and how they are bound at the time the function is invoked or the function is defined. However, it is likely safe to assume static, lexical scoping rules apply.

Pass By Value: change only explicitly named variables.

```
a[1] = 6
a[2] = 2
element = 2
```

Pass By Reference: change explicitly named variables and stuff passed in.

```
a[1] = 9
a[2] = 2
element = 2
```

Pass By Result: change explicitly named variables and stuff passed in.

```
a[1] = 9
a[2] = 2
element = 2
```

Pass By Value-Result: change explicitly named variables and stuff passed in.

```
a[1] = 9
a[2] = 2
element = 2
```

Pass By Name: change explicitly named variables and stuff passed in.

```
a[1] = 6
a[2] = 5
element = 2
```

Comment: "assume dynamic, lexical scoping rules" what the hell is that? Dynamic scoping is the opposite of lexical scoping.

Comment: You are correct -- I started the sentence and changed my mind mid-way through. I will change it.

Comment: You don't sound confused now.

Comment: I don't know what pass by result is, but pass by value-result should result in `a[1] = 4`.